# Python reading JSON value, error

Tags: python, json

I have simple JSON and after for I am reading values inside it.

this is a code:

```
 for row in returned_data['devices']:
     print (row['version'])
```

script print all "version" values and in the end

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 370, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "api.py", line 71, in main
    print (row['version'])
KeyError: 'version'
```

Why?

Comment: can you show us your json?

Comment: This indicates, that the key 'version' does not exist in a row. If you don't care if there are rows with missing version, you can prevent the error by using get function: row.get('version')

Comment: What's the input JSON? It looks like you have there a record inside `returned_data['devices']` which doesn't have key `version`.

Comment: script print all "version" -s and in the end fails, I checked once all json-s arrays has "version"

Comment: Can you post the json please? Just censor sensitive data if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, in runtime some dirty data, I added error handling special vor 'version" keword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need every row to contain the key `version`, you have a mistake in your dictionary, because the exception is indicating, that there is a row, which is missing this key.

In this case you have to check why your dictionary is wrong.

Otherwise, if only some of the rows contain `version` and you don't need every row to have this key, you can get around the error by using `.get()` function like this:

```
for row in returned_data['devices']:
    print (row.get('version'))
```

This prints the version for every row, containing the key and None for the ones without `version`.

Another thing you could do is using a `try...except...`:

```
for row in returned_data['devices']:
    try:
        print (row['version'])
    except KeyError:
        print ("row does not contain 'version'")
```

Comment: Thanks, I has error handling, but especially not check version is exist or not. Seems during json for/each some dirty data coming runtime.